# How to play video that snapShot from firestore inside a Future builder flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, video-player

I have a `StreamBuilder` that gets a snapshot as an array from firestore. And I have a `listview.builder` and child `FutureBuilder` to display a video from `StreamBuilder`'s snapshot, but I am still struggling to display a video on the screen. Please take a look at the code its not have a lot

Here is the code:

```
    VideoPlayerController? _videoPlayerController;
    
      loadVideoPlayer(videoFile) {
        if (_videoPlayerController != null) {
          _videoPlayerController!.dispose();
        }
    
        _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(videoFile);
        _videoPlayerController!.initialize().then((value) {
          setState(() {});
        });
      }
    
    ///SnapShot of videoFile in array
     var videoFile = snapshot.data?["videoFile"];
    
    
   //List view to display all the snapShot videos
    ListView.builder(
             itemCount: videoFile.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
               itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                //Here is the FutureBuilder
                return FutureBuilder(
                     future: downloadVideoURL(videoFile[index]),
                     builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<String>snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==ConnectionState.done 
                      &&snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Column(
                       children: [
                     //Here is where I want to display all the videos  
                       Stack(
                        children: [
                         if (_videoPlayerController != null) ...[
                                AspectRatio(aspectRatio:
                                 _videoPlayerController!.value.aspectRatio,
                                child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController!)),
                           ]],
                           )],
                         );
                     }
             if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
              snapshot.hasData) {
                   return Container();
                       }
                     return Container();
                        });
                          }), 
//To load video url
       Future<String> downloadVideoURL(String videoFile) async {
    try {
      String downloadURL =
          await storage.ref('videos/$videoFile').getDownloadURL();
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(downloadURL);
      return downloadURL;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
    return downloadURL(videoFile);
  }
```

Any idea is good.

Comment: this is not the right way to do this. but what is your problem ?

Comment: Honestly I was not sure If this would work but from the look of it It’s definitely a wrong way. Because I copy it from my display videoFile from pick_image so it would be easier.  If you knows any tutorials or idea. I am open to any suggestions .